# Can I Inherit from this class?

Tags: .net, oop, inheritance

I am trying to create a class that inherits from [SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx).  When I try to compile it throws the error:

> The type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' has
>   no constructors defined

Here is my code:

```
public class MySPListItem : SPListItem
{
    public string ItemUrl {get;set;}
}
```

Is there anyway I can inherit from SPListItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As svick has pointed out, the documentation states that there are no public or protected constructors which means you won't be able to inherit from this class.

I do wonder though, if you're inheriting so that you can extend this class, you might be best off writing some extension methods.

This might be a viable option if that's what you're intending to do, extend the class.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, the class doesn't have any public or protected constructors. That means you can't inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

try defining a constructor:

```
public class MySPListItem : SPListItem
{
   public string ItemUrl {get;set;}

   public MySPListItem():base()
   {
   } 
}
```

**updated**

I agree with @svick!